# Debugging 32bit CASSINI on 64bit OS (Oracle 9)

Tags: debugging, 32bit-64bit, cassini

We are debugging a 32bit application, which connects to oracle using 32bit libraries.
We are able to debug in IIS by setting our application pools to 32bit and using IIS debugging.

We would like to be able to use cassini.

At the moment we are getting TNS listener problems connecting to oracle on 64bit windows 7 using cassini as the debugger.

We have tried building 32bit targets, but this does not help.

There are obviously idiosyncratic issues with this mixed architecture setup. Is there an alternative to cassini, or a way of forcing cassini to be fully 32bit.

The same problems do not occur on a 32bit O/S.

Thanks
Regards
Craig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull the source for [CassiniDev](http://cassinidev.codeplex.com) and build as x64. It serves as a drop-in replacement for the VS 2008/2010 dev servers.